# In NixOS, how can I install an environment with the Python packages SpaCy, pandas, and jenks-natural-breaks?

Tags: python, nixos

I'm very new to NixOS, so please forgive my ignorance. I'm just trying to set up a Python environment---any kind of environment---for developing with SpaCy, the SpaCy data, pandas, and jenks-natural-breaks. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. `pypi2nix -V "3.6" -E gcc -E libffi -e spacy -e pandas -e numpy --default-overrides`, followed by `nix-build -r requirements.nix -A packages`. I've managed to get the first command to work, but the second fails with `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas==0.23.4)`
2. Writing a default.nix that looks like this: `with import <nixpkgs> {};
   python36.withPackages (ps: with ps; [ spacy pandas scikitlearn ])`. This fails with `collision between /nix/store/9szpqlby9kvgif3mfm7fsw4y119an2kb-python3.6-msgpack-0.5.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msgpack/_packer.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so and /nix/store/d08bgskfbrp6dh70h3agv16s212zdn6w-python3.6-msgpack-python-0.5.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msgpack/_packer.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
3. Making a new virtualenv, and then running `pip install` on all these packages. Scikit-learn fails to install, with `fish: Unknown command 'ar rc build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/liblibsvm-skl.a build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.o'`

I guess ideally I'd like to install this environment with nix, so that I could enter it with nix-shell, and so other environments could reuse the same python packages. How would I go about doing that? Especially since some of these packages exist in nixpkgs, and others are only on Pypi.

Comment: I don't have this problem yet, but I probably will soon, so I wrapped up my notes so far into a github repo: https://github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/nix_sf_answer

If/when I solve it I'll create an answer and post it here.  You may find the notes helpful.

Comment: "Soon" I said, 3.5 years ago... then today I ran across this thread.  I'm still not a nix master, but I have learned some since then--see my answer below.

Comment: Re: collisions, you can (and should) specify priority order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Caveat

I had trouble with [jenks-natural-breaks](https://pypi.org/project/jenks-natural-breaks/) to the tune of

```
nix-shell ❯ poetry run python -c 'import jenks_natural_breaks'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/matt/2022/12/28-2/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jenks_natural_breaks/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._jenks_matrices import ffi as _ffi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jenks_natural_breaks._jenks_matrices'
```

So I'm going to use [jenkspy](https://pypi.org/project/jenkspy/) which appears to be a bit livelier.  If that doesn't scratch your itch, I'd contact the maintainer of `jenks-natural-breaks` for guidance

##### Flakes

you said:

> so other environments could reuse the same python packages

Which makes me think that a `flake.nix` is what you need. What's cool about flakes is that you can define an environment that has `spacy`, `pandas`, and `jenkspy` with one flake.  And then you (or somebody else) might say:

> I want an env like Jonathan's, except I also want `sympy`

and rather than copying your env and making tweaks, they can declare your env as a build input and write a `flake.nix` with their modifications--which can be further modified by others.

One could imagine a sort of family-tree of environments, so you just need to pick the one that suits your task.  The python community has not yet converged on this vision.

##### Poetry

Poetry will treat you like you're trying to publish a library when all you asked for is an environment, but a library's dependencies are pretty much an environment so there's nothing wrong with having an empty package and just using poetry as an environment factory.

Bonus: if you decide to publish a library after all, you're ready.

##### The Setup

nix flakes thinks in terms of git repo's, so we'll start with one:

```
$ git init
```

Then create a file called `flake.nix`. Usually I end up with poetry handling 90% of the python stuff, but both `pandas` and `spacy` are in that 10% that has dependencies which link to system libraries.  So we ask nix to install them so that when poetry tries to install them in the `nix develop` shell, it has what it needs.

```hs
{
  description = "Jonathan's awesome env";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs";
  };


  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }: (flake-utils.lib.eachSystem [
    "x86_64-linux"
    "x86_64-darwin"
    "aarch64-linux"
    "aarch64-darwin"
  ] (system:
    let
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
    in
    rec {
      packages.jonathansenv = pkgs.poetry2nix.mkPoetryApplication {
        projectDir = ./.;
      };

      defaultPackage = packages.jonathansenv;

      devShell = pkgs.mkShell {
        buildInputs = [
          pkgs.poetry
          pkgs.python310Packages.pandas
          pkgs.python310Packages.spacy
        ];
      };
    }));
}
```

Now we let git know about the flake and enter the environment:

```bash
❯ git add flake.nix
❯ nix develop
$
```

Then we initialize the poetry project.  I've found that poetry, installed by nix, is kind of odd about which python it uses by default, so we'll set it explicitly

```bash
$ poetry init  # follow prompts
$ poetry env use $(which python)
$ poetry run python --version
    Python 3.10.9 # declared in the flake.nix
```

At this point, we should have a `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "jonathansenv"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
jenkspy = "^0.3.2"
spacy = "^3.4.4"
pandas = "^1.5.2"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

##### Usage

Now we create the venv that poetry will use, and run a command that depends on these.

```bash
$ poetry install
$ poetry run python -c 'import jenkspy, spacy, pandas'
```

You can also have poetry put you in a shell:

```bash
$ poetry shell
(venv)$ python -c 'import jenkspy, spacy, pandas'
```

It's kind of awkward to do so though, because we're two subshells deep and any shell customizations that we have the grandparent shell are not available.  So I recommend using [direnv](https://github.com/nix-community/nix-direnv), to enter the dev shell whenever I navigate to that directory and then just use `poetry run ...` to run commands in the environment.

##### Publishing the env

In addition to running `nix develop` with the `flake.nix` in your current dir, you can also do `nix develop /local/path/to/repo` or `develop nix develop github:/githubuser/githubproject` to achieve the same result.

To demonstrate the github example, I have pushed the files referenced above [here](https://github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/nix-flake-pandas-spacy).  So you ought to be able to run this from any linux shell with nix installed:

```
❯ nix develop github:/MatrixManAtYrService/nix-flake-pandas-spacy
$ poetry install
$ poetry run python -c 'import jenkspy, spacy, pandas'
```

I say "ought" because if I run that command on a mac it complains about `linux-headers-5.19.16` being unsupported on `x86_64-darwin`.

Presumably there's a way to write the flake (or fix a package) so that it doesn't insist on building linux stuff on a mac, but until I figure it out I'm afraid that this is only a partial answer.

Comment: poetry2nix generate flakes (https://github.com/nix-community/poetry2nix#using-the-flake) that don't use `pkgs.poetry` but instead use `poetry2nix.packages.${system}.poetry`.  Hypothesis: my MacOS problems will go away if I start doing this.  When I have occasion to test this hypothesis, I'll report back.